# If I use Extend Spell on Lesser Vigor, does it extend the maximum number of rounds it can last?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, feats

Lesser Vigor lasts for 10 rounds + 1 round/level, up to 15 rounds. If I use Extend Spell on it, is the limit still 15 rounds?

Comment: Tangential question: is the intent on using a Wand of Extended Lesser Vigor?

Comment: no, it would cost 6 times more, and heal twice as much, bad deal

Comment: Asked as part of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102272/8610) and addressed in its answers. It's cool if this stands alone, though.

Comment: Might want to have the character see a cleric (domain, urology) about that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following Sage Advice/FAQ quotes on [the playground](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?70594-Stupid-Newb-question-about-Extend-Spell).

The main quote:

> **Main 3.5 FAQ, Revision 06/30/2008, p. 40**
>
> **Q**: The *Vigor* series of spells (*CD*) raise an interesting question. Does the built-in maximum duration of each spell limitation override the effect of the *Extend Spell* feat?
>
> **A**: Yes. *Extend Spell* still increases the spell’s duration, but only up to the spell’s listed maximum duration. Use either the normal maximum duration or the doubled duration, whichever is less. If a 7th-level druid used *Extend Spell* on her *Vigor* spell, the duration could not increase beyond 25 rounds.

Which is corroborated by a second quote:

> **Main 3.5 FAQ, Revision 06/30/2008, p. 92**
>
> **Q**: The *Mass Lesser Vigor* spell has a fixed range (of 20 feet), which makes it eligible for the revised *Persistent Spell* feat in *P.G.*. Does that mean a 17th-level druid could use a 9th-level spell slot to give nine creatures fast healing 1 for 24 hours, or does the built-in limit of 25 rounds make that pointless?
>
> **A**: Unlike *Extend Spell*, *Persistent Spell* replaces a spell’s normal duration with a new duration of 24 hours. In this case, the effect overrides the normal maximum duration of the spell, so it would indeed grant nine creatures fast healing 1 for 24 hours (a pretty reasonable effect for a 9th-level spell).

The FAQ itself can be downloaded [here](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/er/20070731a); I have amended the quotes with the latest revision.

---

The FAQ is not necessarily authoritative, and sometimes of dubious quality; it is up to you whether you choose to follow its ruling or not.

If you do choose to follow them, then the rulings are clear:

- *Extend Spell* doubles the normal spell duration of a spell, up to the specified maximum duration if any.
- *Persist Spell* simply overrides any duration to 24 hours.